# Can I use same values alt="name" for two or more img html elements in single page?

Tags: html, accessibility, w3c, w3c-validation

I am using two logos in one page and my code is

```
<img src="img/logo/logo-black.png" alt="logo" class="logo-white"/>
```

and

```
<img src="img/logo/logo-black.png" alt="logo" class="logo-black"/>
```

when I validated this code I have receive the following message, I am not sure this is an error or not. Have a look at the screenshot and let me know what is the message about.  [image: w3c report]

Comment: Did you read the sentences above the table that clearly tell you what to do? What don't you understand?

Comment: It should be `</pre>`, not `<pre/>`. And `pre`  elements should be used for preformatted text, not for images.

Comment: If two or more images have the same alt text, blind people can't know at which one they're "looking" when navigating the page.

Comment: I am little bit confused about that message. let me know is this valid or not and what is meant by not resolvable?

Comment: @Oriol sorry I have correct the format now check the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The validation basically says this:

Your HTML IS validated from a technical point of view, no software will encounter problems when parsing it, but having duplicated `ALT`s have a very high chance of not accurately representing your pictures and which would then lead to an incorrect information when the image can't be loaded, or incorrect interpretation of your images by screen readers.

But still, if you're 100% sure your images are the exact same, having the same `alt` text should be nothing but fine.

Answer (score 2):

**You can perfectly use the same alternative text as long as the text is meaningful.**

For instance:

```
<img src="jack1.jpg" alt="Portrait of Jack Smith" />
<img src="jack2.jpg" alt="Portrait of Jack Smith" />
```

**BUT** an alternative text like **logo** is not meaningful, you should replace it by **logo of some company name** or by a blank alternative `alt=""` if the image is here for decorative purpose

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

The `alt` tag is alternate text. That is its displayed when the image doesn't load.

You "can" use same `alt` but you **shouldn't**!

`alt` should always be a meaningful line describing what the image is.

What if the user's page doesn't load fast enough and he gets to see the `alt` tags? or What if your page is being parsed by a browser for visually-impared?

***Always use meaningful alternate text tags for images so that the users who may not see the image at-least get a gist of what should have shown up there.***

Comment: Thanks for help, I appreciate your help

Comment: Good to know it helped :)